# What is a "domain" in the context of AuthPlugin in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, authentication, mediawiki

I'm writing my own [AuthPlugin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/AuthPlugin) for MediaWiki, and refering to [the doc](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classAuthPlugin.html) and [the code](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/AuthPlugin.php?view=markup) provided officially. There're several functions about **domain**:

```
AuthPlugin::domainList()
// Get a list of domains (in HTMLForm options format) used.

AuthPlugin::getDomain()
// Get the user's domain.

AuthPlugin::setDomain($domain)
// Set the domain this plugin is supposed to use when authenticating.
```

However, I don't understand what is a **domain**, how is it supposed to be? Is it whatever the writer of the AuthPlugin extension wants it to be, rather than having any significance in a default MW configuration?

Comment: I would assume it literally means domain, as in stackoverflow.com etc. But it is ambiguous from the docs.

Comment: @kennypu Do you have any idea whether I can ignore it?

Comment: i'm not familiar with it so no clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly for the LDAP plugin; if your auth system doesn't have a concept of multiple domains that might need to be selected from then you don't need to worry about it.